# Visa checkout Integration

Tags: paypal, credit-card, android-pay

I am trying to integrate visa checkout on a site which uses paypal payment processing.
Earlier we integrated Google Wallet on our site and google wallet returned a discover card for any card selected from the google wallet and we were just passing the card details to paypal for furthur payment processing. The card response from google wallet looked something like this

```
"aud": "01409448849434218847",
"iat": 1424749827,
"exp": 1424753427
},
"pan": "6011988571714740",
"cvn": "827"
```

where pan is the discover card number and cvn is the cvv number.

But in case of visa checkout, the cvv number is not returned. A sample payment data response from visa checkout looks like this

```
{
"paymentRequest": {
"currencyCode": "USD",
"total": "10"
},
"userData": {
"userFirstName": "XYZ",
"userLastName": "XYZ",
"userName": "XYZ@gmail.com",
"userEmail": "XYZ@gmail.com",
"encUserId": "kFilkXPMqx9P2sxVBwZpwHZ3ZppIJSASFXOlMt/u/SU="
},
"creationTimeStamp": 1427169634910,
"paymentInstrument": {
"id": "Rjgzv/9FVVM09JiLGNHzqZlnc+h0vTA8E/NPESuZvOU=",
"lastFourDigits": "xxxx",
"binSixDigits": "xxxxxx",
"paymentType": {
  "cardBrand": "VISA",
  "cardType": "PREPAID"
 },
 "billingAddress": {
  "personName": "XYZ ABC",
  "line1": "131 Dartmouth St",
  "city": "Boston",
  "stateProvinceCode": "MA",
  "postalCode": "02116",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "phone": "9123456789"
  },
  "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
  "expired": false,
  "cardArts": {
  "cardArt": [
    {
      "baseImageFileName":    "https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/VmeCardArts/uWOvgFoQISxPh_MWE7gO8xJHi_Kwti3ZgptHQ1LkSR4.png",
      "height": 50,
      "width": 77
    }
  ]
},
"issuerBid": "14",
"nameOnCard": "XYZ ABC",
"expirationDate": {
  "month": "01",
  "year": "2018"
 }
},
"shippingAddress": {
"id": "vn9XOKl/FOLHzEOrs2KoF3qA2VoFoQoaz6phbibsCVE=",
"verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
"personName": "XYZ ABC",
"line1": "131 Dartmouth St",
"city": "Boston",
"stateProvinceCode": "MA",
"postalCode": "02116",
"countryCode": "US",
"phone": "9123456789",
"default": false
},
"riskData": {
"advice": "LOW",
"score": 0,
"avsResponseCode": "Y",
"cvvResponseCode": "M"
},
"partialShippingAddress": {
"countryCode": "US",
"postalCode": "02116"
}
}
```

Here we don't get the actual CVV number.

Any idea, how we can proceed with the paypal payment processing without the cvv number. (The card number comes as account number, but is not present in this response).

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you will never receive the CVV number [per Visa](https://community.developer.visa.com/t5/Visa-Payment-Technologies/3-Digit-CVV-number-in-response/m-p/468#U468).  You will instead receive a letter value indicating a match or not.  They say that is enough to process the payment.